# Как узнать сколько места в памяти занимает матрица или массив?

Tags: python, numpy

Eсть ли какая-нибудь функция, которая позволяет узнать, сколько места в памяти занимает матрица или массив numpy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом [nbytes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.nbytes.html):

```
In [5]: a = np.random.rand(10**6)

In [6]: a.nbytes
Out[6]: 8000000

In [7]: a.dtype
Out[7]: dtype('float64')
```

это работает и для многомерных матриц:

```
In [11]: a = np.random.randint(0, 10, (10**3, 10**3, 10**3), dtype=np.int8)

In [12]: a.shape
Out[12]: (1000, 1000, 1000)

In [13]: a.nbytes
Out[13]: 1000000000

In [14]: a.dtype
Out[14]: dtype('int8')
```

также можно воспользоваться стандартной функцией: [sys.getsizeof()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof)

```
In [33]: a = np.random.rand(10**6)

In [34]: sys.getsizeof(a)
Out[34]: 8000096
```

которая вызовет `__sizeof__` для вызываемого объекта:

```
In [35]: a.__sizeof__()
Out[35]: 8000096
```

Из документации:

> **getsizeof()** calls the object’s __ **sizeof** __ method and adds an
>   additional garbage collector overhead if the object is managed by the
>   garbage collector.

Comment: В простом случае, `numpy.array` можно рассматривать как кусок памяти с соответствующими метаданными (тип, размеры, где/что лежит). `.nbytes` возвращает размер куска памяти (место занимаемое элементами массива—в идеализированной модели: возможно игнорируя выравнивание, вспомогательные структуры), не учитывая метаданные. `sys.getsizeof()` обещает вернуть размер Питон-объекта (`numpy.array()`) в байтах, что может включать в себя место и под метаданные (иногда мусор возвращается). Эти цифры следует рассматривать как *оценки* необходимой памяти, а фактическую память можно узнать измерениями.